# Folders uploaded with CLI don't have proper ACL (files are ok, only folders have issues)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl, aws-cli, typo3-8.x

So I'm trying to move assets from server to S3.

Assets are for a typo3 environment. My problem seems to be with the S3 though. For some reason it doesn't provide proper access permissions to folders.

**Created** folders seem to work properly, while folders uploaded via the browser or aws-cli don't get proper permissions. The files inside the folders are ok, readable and writable. But TYPO3 also needs the folders. Otherwise I get some big nasty errors everywhere.

This is my first time working with S3, so the question is: am I doing something wrong in the permissions/settings, or is this a known problem with S3? And if I messed something up, any pointers where to look?

This is my bucket policy for the project. user/project changed for security reasons.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "someID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Read and write access for typo3 system",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::user/project"
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::project/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Public read access",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::project/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I've also added a CORS config since the bucket serves as asset storage for the typo3 system. domain changed for security reasons.

```
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*.domain.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

As I said, creating the folders manually in either typo3 backend or the S3 management console works fine.
Uploading in the S3 management console, or syncing with aws-cli doesn't.

(sorry, can't post images as I don't have enough "reputation")

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T88Su.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj8MS.png

And when selecting a folder that contains other such broken folders, there's an orange error showing in TYPO3's Filelist module:

```
Error executing "GetObjectAcl" on "https://project.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_folder/uploaded_with_cli/?acl"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: 
`GET https://project.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test_folder/uploaded_with_cli/?acl` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: <?xml version="1.0" 
encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message> (truncated...) NoSuchKey (client): The specified
 key does not exist. - <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>
test_folder/uploaded_with_cli/</Key><RequestId>****randomkey****</RequestId><HostId>****randomsecretkey****</HostId></Error>
```

The marked **randomkey** and **randomsecretkey** seem to be random strings similar to the id & secretkey, but each broken folder generates such an error with a completely different key set. I checked, none of them are the real id & secret key for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those looking for a way to fix Filelist issues in typo3 while using S3, you need to add ACL to all folders.

Create an S3Client object:

```
$s3 = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'region' => $region,
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => [
            'key' => $key,
            'secret' => $secret,
        ]
    ]);
```

And add the ACL to each "folder" you have:

```
$s3->putObject([
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $folderToCreate,
            'Body' => '',
            'ACL' => 'public-read'
        ]);
```

You can go with a simple .txt file that contains a list of your folders

```
find -type d -printf "%P\n" > dirs.txt
```

Or, if you like overengineered, you could list all existing objects in an array with

```
try {
        $results = $s3->getPaginator('ListObjects', [
            'Bucket' => $bucket
        ]);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            foreach ($result['Contents'] as $object) {
                array_push($allObjects, $object['Key']);
            }
        }
    } catch (S3Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
```

, from where you'll have to:

remove the files (you only need a directory listing). You can use pathinfo() for this)

remove duplicates

remove the "." and/or ".." values

you'll probably also want to set the ACL for subdirectories that make up the path to your files (for cases where there are no files in the subdirectories that make up your path)

```
foreach ($allPaths as $longpath) {
        $explodedpath = explode('/', $longpath);

        $goodPathValue = '';

        foreach ($explodedpath as $segment) {

            if ($goodPathValue == '') {
                $goodPathValue = $segment;
            } else {

                // if it's not the first folder, we append the segment to it with a slash in between
                $goodPathValue .= "/" . $segment;
            }

            // at this point we either have first folder, or a part of the full path, which we enter in the array if it's unique
            if (!in_array($goodPathValue, $allPaths)) {
                array_push($allPaths, $goodPathValue);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is how the .txt or array should look like for optimal results

```
downloads
downloads/en
downloads/en/user_upload
downloads/en/user_upload/Products
downloads/en/user_upload/Markets
```

Answer (score 0):

S3 has no concept of directories (folders). S3 is an object store where each object is identified by a key. The key might be a string like "logs/2014/06/04/system.log"

Most graphical user interfaces on top of S3 (AWS CLI, AWS Console, Cloudberry, Transmit etc ...) interpret the "/" characters as a directory separator and present the file list "as is" it was in a directory structure.

However, internally, there is no concept of directory, S3 has a flat namespace. See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html for more details.

Given this, it is normal you can not define permission on folders, as there is no folder on S3.  Some GUI tools create empty file to represent folders, some don't.  I don't know how Typo3 is handling "folders" on S3.